# Upload app in Android Market which is already there

Tags: android, google-play, android-market-filtering

I am developing a game for Android. This game is Pacman, I have seen it is already on Android Market. Anyway I would like to upload my app to Android when it is done. I am not looking for earning money, I just want to learn to program with Android SDK and I would like to put my app in Android app in order to put this in my CV. It would be for free.
Do you think there is any problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Visit this site:
http://www.android.com/us/developer-content-policy.html#showlanguages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The owners of Pacman can claim infringement and have it taken down, at least don't call it Pacman, that might help.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see any problem in this.
You just have to pay a 1 time fee of $25

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with app with the same name. Main thing - is difference in `packageName` param in manifests file.
So, you can register for publishing on market(25$), and release your app with no problems.